# phpMyAdmin not able to uplaoad a db

Tags: php, sql, database, docker, phpmyadmin

I want to upload a big db to my localhost(docker with apache). The first problem was that I can't upload a big file than I add a uploads.ini and add it to the docker-compose.yml. Now you can see in phpMyAdmin that I can upload 200Mib. Then there was an error that the execution time is too long. Then I add the max_execution_time to the uploads.ini and there is another error that says

`(Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in /var/www/html/libraries/classes/File.php on line 741)`

and I don't have any idea how I can find out where the code is. Please help me!

Comment: _"I don't have any idea how I can find out where the code is"_ - Did you check where the error message says the error occurred? (`/var/www/html/libraries/classes/File.php` on line `741`)

Comment: In my local directory there is no file like this. There are no directorys like this.

Comment: The path is from your docker container (if that is where you have the web server and PHP installed). I'm guessing that you've mapped some local folder to docker `/var/www/html`? In that case, check if you have this: `libraries/classes/File.php` in your project. The file do exist somewhere since that's where the error occurs and since we don't know much about your setup, it's hard for us to know exactly where.

Comment: In my project there is some complete other folders. In the first folder there are to folders. `_docker` and `web` in web is normal wordpress data. In _docker is a other folder called `php` there are 4 files. first of all there is a file called `000-default.conf` than there is the `Dockerfile` and the `php.ini` and the last file is the `uploads.ini`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by unzip my db and then uploaded it to phpMyAdmin. I am not sure why there was a error with a zip file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that, while you modified the phpMyAdmin directive `$cfg['MemoryLimit']`, you may have not adjusted the PHP configuration values that also affect resource limits. You may wish to refer to the [phpMyAdmin FAQ entry on the subject](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems), which shows several `php.ini` directives you'll also need to adjust. In your case, you're hitting the `max_execution_time` limit, but you probably need to increase all of these:

- `max_execution_time`,
- `upload_max_filesize`,
- `memory_limit`, and
- `post_max_size`

Comment: This is my problem. I edit all of this but it's not working. I don't understand why there is this error massage.

Comment: How have you set all of those values, are you overriding them on the command line or passing a modified php.ini to your container? I'd also take a look at the output of `phpinfo()` to verify whether the new values are active.